# Image fit in browser without scrollbars except below certain sizes

Tags: css

With CSS: how to automatically resize image to fit in browser as below:

- keep image always visible (without horizontal/vertical scrollbars)
- if browser size is less than 400 width or 300 height scrollbars are used

I try this but this is not what I need:

```
.ajustImageToScreenResolution 
{
    max-width: 100%;   
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

EDIT : I created a jsfiddle to try the solution of antyrat but as you can see when page size is enlarged we see vertical scrollbar and I don't want that. I prefer seeing the whole image height without scrollbar.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ar9h0vyh/

Comment: Does it have to be an <img /> or can it be the background to a <div>?

Comment: Need to be an `<img/>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
.ajustImageToScreenResolution {
    min-width: 400px;
    min-height: 300px;   
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

It will resize image to full width and height untill it will reach `400px` width and `300px` height.

Comment: I'm guessing he wants it to occupy the whole screen, even in it's height, and no deformation. It'll crop if it's too big. Just guessing..

Comment: Your solution show vertical scrollbars when browser is maximized. I need my image without scrollbars (except below 400 width or 300 height then scrollbars are used)

Comment: @Bronzato Add `margin:0;` and `padding:0;` to body element.

Comment: @Bronzato or you can add to `.ajustImageToScreenResolution` class `position:fixed; top:0; left: 0;`

Comment: With `position:fixed` my image is stretched and I don't want that :(

Comment: @Bronzato and what about zero padding and margins? Can you show me example of jsFiddle?

Comment: I try zero padding and margin and still the same problem. I'll create a jsFiddle.

Comment: @Bronzato so just add `overflow: hidden;` to body http://jsfiddle.net/ar9h0vyh/1/

Answer (score 0):

1) Put width and `height 100%`, and set the minimum width and height with `min-height` and `min-width`

exqample http://jsfiddle.net/41ytsjfb/

```
.ajustImageToScreenResolution 
{
    width: 100%;   
    height: 100%;
  min-height:400px
}
```

2) If you want to use image as background http://jsfiddle.net/41ytsjfb/1/
In this case you will also need to set the `background-size:cover` property

Comment: Your solution show vertical scrollbars when browser is maximized. I need my image without scrollbars (except below 400 width or 300 height then scrollbars are used)